# Password protection doesn't prompt for password on pages

Tags: posts, themes

Have a brand new WordPress page where if one selects "Password protected" page in the page editor, it displays `Protected: <page title>` in the header of the page/page navigation, but does not prompt for the set password.

It does display the contents that are supposed to be loaded only after password verification. I have tried to illicit this password prompt after clearing cookies, and just in case using a browser I hardly ever use (IE, and especially not for working with/browsing my site)

What I have already tried to solve this, found on wordpress forum/help pages, in order, without luck:

- Switched back to a default wordpress theme
- Deactivated all plugins

Some folks mention augmenting the theme's `functions.php` file with functions that provide this functionality for theme's that strangely don't implement this functionality, but don't provide enough info on how.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131050/discussion-on-question-by-user66001-password-protection-doesnt-prompt-for-passw).

Answer (score 0):

Your posts password form does not show because you typed the password in and unlocked the post, and it remembers you from when you submitted the password via cookies.

It doesn't have to be this particular post either, entering a password unlocks all posts that use that password present and future.

Comment: Not sure how that can be positively determined from someone not aware of the page in question, hence this question should be such in a comment. Have tried this on multiple browsers, including one I *never* use for editing this site until now.

Comment: you don't have to do it for that specific post, entering a password will unlock _all_ posts with that password

Comment: see https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-password-protection/#password-protecting-many-posts-and-pages

Comment: Sigh. I am also aware of how cookies work. I have one page that I have ever set as password protected on the site, and looked at all the other pages and none of them have password protection.

Comment: so we do not know if password protection is broken, or if this is a unique issue to that specific post. You've already said that this happens on a vanilla WP install, with the default theme, and no plugins installed, so I don't see how this is possible unless WordPress itself was modified, there was user error, or there is code running that has not been shared, e.g. MU plugins, plugins considered mission critical, hosting software, etc.

Comment: At this point I'm struggling to see how this is a development problem and not either a WP bug or a user support problem ( both of which are offtopic here, this is a stack for programming questions ). Ask your host/server admins to replace WP fresh, otherwise report it as a bug to WP

Comment: I never said I tried this on vanilla WP. I stated I deactivated all plugins and switched back to the default theme, now 3 times. I am now just seeing the "development" part of the sub site title. Note I did not elect for this to be moved here. Feel it best for this answer to be removed, along with all it's comments, and moved back to where I originally intended to get support/advise/whatever the appropriate name is (Super User).

Comment: The question isn't suited to that stack and they're likely to close or punt back here. It was likely migrated here because you explicitly mentioned filters in code. I use the term vanilla in the sense of standard, mainstream, unmodified, no additional changes, the default. If you are not using vanilla standard WordPress then what fork of WordPress are you using? Classicpress? If you choose to delete your own question that is your decision

Comment: The very act of adding a plugin or theme means one cannot *guarantee* getting back to vanilla, without starting from scratch, as just like Windows installers, one cannot be sure all changes are rolled back by a plugin, unless there is Wordpress functionality I am aware of that monitors plugin installation script actions, or takes a snapshot of the prior state of the install.

Comment: Installing a plugin does not modify WordPress itself on the filesystem, plugins are self contained in folders in the `wp-content/plugin` folder. WordPress itself has a well known specific file and folder structure, to the point that many hosts checksum the files and compare against known good lists for security checks. A plugin can only modify WP core behaviour at runtime, they're not like phpbb patches or Windows installers.

Comment: the contents of `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` as well as most of the top level files except `wp-config.php` are never to be modified, and are never touched except to update WordPress. Additional files in those folders or modifications are considered extreme bad practice, and isn't possible on many hosts as an added layer of security. Snapshots aren't needed, replacing WP core with a fresh download should have no ill effects if all is good. WP's own updater is built under this assumption and will destroy any mods you add when updating

Comment: Given your comments imply that altering core wordpress files are possible, and I cannot provide you how this is hosted to have more confidence in eliminating this as a cause, one cannot say that vanilla = not altered, and not vanilla = fresh. Given replacing those folders have potential to remove my ability to roll back the changes (by logging into the interface that allows me to use something like File Explorer plugin) sans access to the filesystem directly, this is not an option.

Comment: Your server admins/host can answer that question for you. Modifying WP core is something people who are new or unfamiliar to WordPress might do. Also you are incorrect, plugins are not stored in `wp-admin` and `wp-includes`. Plugins are self contained packages, your concern is based on the assumption that a plugins files and WordPress' files are intermingled like when you run a Windows installer, that is not the case. You can delete `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` and replace the with fresh versions safely, and you should not notice any difference. WordPress itself does it on update.

Comment: Note that modifying WordPress core is rare and extremely unusual, I mention it because you systematically eliminated all the other places that could have contained code changes. If someone has modified WP core then this is a major security risk that must be addressed. Any fears of not being able to rollback suggest that you do not have backups, and are unaware of the WP folder structure. Plugins and themes are kept in the `wp-content` folder, that folder is not considered WordPress core and is where user modified files and packages such as plugins, themes, and uploads are located.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include this code in your template or you will not see any password field and the page will simply load normally.

```php
<?php
if (post_password_required()) { 
    echo get_the_password_form();
} else { 
    // your protected template code here
}
?>
```

To make it easier, you can close the php to insert your straight HTML and such:

```
<?php
if (post_password_required()) { 
    echo get_the_password_form();
} else { ?>
    <!-- your HTML code here -->
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank-you! This is along the lines of what I mentioned in my original question I had seen before. Last question - Where does this code go? Hoping the answer isn't each page one wants to put a password on. I was hoping there is a template file, as eluded to in your answer, that this can be inserted into in order to apply to any page that theme presents which one at any point in the future wants to password protect?

Comment: this check is already built into `get_the_content` in WordPress core: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/b2117d72991ba7ece278311ada385bd4b20488bf/wp-includes/post-template.php#L314-L316 modifying the theme to do this is unnecessary, it won't change the behaviour, themes support this without any changes and the OP has already stated this happens in the default WP themes which definitely support passworded posts. The solution to this question won't be an addition to the theme, something needed to be added to WP or modified to cause this kind of behaviour, this is not normal

Comment: @user66001 it goes in your template for whichever page/post you want it on. If you're using the same template, then you'll only need to add it once. @tom-j-nowell Not all themes are using `get_the_content` or `the_content` to show all of the data, or it might be in a spot that reveals other content you'd rather not have shown. Example: the last project I was working on. Client only wanted the page title to show and all else to be hidden, and all data was from custom fields. He didn't say what theme he was using, only that he tried the default, so thought the theme might be the problem.

Comment: @liquidRock the default themes use it, otherwise the theme would need to ignore post content or fetch it directly from the database. The OP reports that they're experiencing this on all themes including the twentytwenty theme with all plugins deactivated, so no pagebuilders. Check the chat link in the comment on the question, I asked a lot of questions about the OP's setup

Comment: Will do. Could be a plug-in conflict or something else out of whack.

Comment: @liquidRock I never said all themes were experiencing this. I have tried Escapade and twentytwenty and those two were. Alas when I put in your second example to the "Shop" page by switching to text view, updated, checked rendered page (no change), and returned to the edit-page page, it had been switched to `&nbsp; <h2><span style="color: #ff00ff;"><strong>DEMO/TEST; DO NOT USE TO PURCHASE PRODUCT</strong></span></h2> <!--?php } ?-->`. <h2>, and the contents of it, was what was there originally.

Comment: @liquidRock - Could you advise how to inspect what the theme is using to show all of the data, as in what it is doing prior to rending what is put in the edit page interface?

Comment: @user66001 I build my own themes and have no ideas what a demo theme is doing. It sounds from your text that it is restricting things. The only thing you can do is open the PHP template files and see how they are coded. Short of that, no way to know. I also made a comment in the discussion you may want to try. If TwentyTwenty isn't working with passwords, something is broken somewhere.